# При прокрутке сайта на айфон происходят залипания

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://jardaxion.github.io/eeaar - при скорлле сайта на айфон происходят залипания на слайдерах(Сделаны на slick slider), так же там имеются position absolute элементы

```
section.sliderMain 
        .sliderMain__inner
            .sliderMain__leftArrow.sliderMain__arrow
                svg(width='14' height='16' viewbox='0 0 14 16' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
                    path(d='M0.292893 7.29289C-0.0976315 7.68342 -0.0976315 8.31658 0.292893 8.70711L6.65685 15.0711C7.04738 15.4616 7.68054 15.4616 8.07107 15.0711C8.46159 14.6805 8.46159 14.0474 8.07107 13.6569L2.41421 8L8.07107 2.34315C8.46159 1.95262 8.46159 1.31946 8.07107 0.928932C7.68054 0.538408 7.04738 0.538408 6.65685 0.928932L0.292893 7.29289ZM14 7L1 7V9L14 9V7Z' fill='#414141')
            .sliderMain__content
                -for(let i=0; i<4; i++)
                    .slide__wrapper
                        .slider__slide
                            .slide__left
                                p.slide__title Авторский курс "Сертификация от 0 до успеха!"  
                                p.slide__descirption Оставьте заявку и получите скидку на любой пакет
                                a.button.slide__button.js-open-modal(href="#", data-modal="request") Оставить заявку
                            .slide__right
                                .slider__first
                                    svg(width='154' height='154' viewbox='0 0 154 154' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
                                        circle(cx='77' cy='77' r='77' fill='#F3E7D6')
                                .slider__second
                                    svg(width='107' height='107' viewbox='0 0 107 107' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
                                        path(d='M107 53.5C107 83.0472 83.0472 107 53.5 107C23.9528 107 0 83.0472 0 53.5C0 23.9528 23.9528 0 53.5 0C83.0472 0 107 23.9528 107 53.5ZM16.05 53.5C16.05 74.1831 32.8169 90.95 53.5 90.95C74.1831 90.95 90.95 74.1831 90.95 53.5C90.95 32.8169 74.1831 16.05 53.5 16.05C32.8169 16.05 16.05 32.8169 16.05 53.5Z' fill='#CD474A')
                                .slide__img-wrp
                                    img.slide__img(src='img/woman.png', alt="")
                                    .slide__backcircle
                                        svg(width='357' height='357' viewbox='0 0 357 357' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
                                            circle(cx='178.5' cy='178.5' r='178' stroke='#CD474A')
            .sliderMain__rightArrow.sliderMain__arrow
                svg(width='14' height='16' viewbox='0 0 14 16' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
                    path(d='M13.7071 8.70711C14.0976 8.31658 14.0976 7.68342 13.7071 7.29289L7.34315 0.928933C6.95262 0.538408 6.31946 0.538408 5.92893 0.928933C5.53841 1.31946 5.53841 1.95262 5.92893 2.34315L11.5858 8L5.92893 13.6569C5.53841 14.0474 5.53841 14.6805 5.92893 15.0711C6.31946 15.4616 6.95262 15.4616 7.34315 15.0711L13.7071 8.70711ZM-8.74228e-08 9L13 9L13 7L8.74228e-08 7L-8.74228e-08 9Z' fill='#414141')
```

```scss
/* Сам блок и стрелки */
.sliderMain{
    &__inner{
        padding: 94px 114px 75px 186px;
        position: relative;
    }

    &__arrow{
        padding: 16px 18px 15px 18px;
        background: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.6);
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        @include verCenterAbsol;
    }

    @include LRea('&__leftArrow', 169px, '&__rightArrow', 140px);

    .slick-dots{
        display: flex;
        @include flexCenter;
        margin-top: 74px;
        li{
            &:not(:last-of-type){
                margin-right: 10px;
            }

            &.slick-active{
                .slider__dots{
                    transform: scale(1.5);
                    background: black;
                }
                + li{
                    .slider__dots{
                        transform: scale(1.2);
                        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/* Настройки внутри самого слайдера */
.slider{
    &__slide{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin: 0 126px;
        padding-top: 71px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
    }

    &__dots{
        @include box(7px, 50%);
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
        @include transition;
    }

    &__first{
        position: absolute;
        @include TLa(-70px, -49px);
        z-index: 3;
    }

    &__second{
        position: absolute;
        @include BRa;
        z-index: 3;
    }
}

/* Слайд */
.slide{
    &__title{
        color: #0D2938;
        font-size: 48px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        max-width: 763px;
        line-height: 60px;
    }

    &__left{
        margin-bottom: 23px;
    }

    &__right{
        position: relative;
    }

    &__descirption{
        color: #A6A6A6;
        margin-bottom: 69px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    &__button{
        padding: 20px 90px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    &__img{
        width: 351px;
        height: 348px;
        object-fit: scale-down;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        &-wrp{
            position: relative;
            svg{
                position: absolute;
                @include BRa(-9px, -12px)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```js
$('.sliderMain__content').slick({
        nextArrow: '.sliderMain__rightArrow',
        prevArrow: '.sliderMain__leftArrow',
        customPaging : function(slider, i) {
            return '<div class="slider__dots"></div>';
        },
        dots: true,
        autoplay: true,
        speed: 650,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        slidesPerRow: 1,
        infinite: true,
        swipe: false
    });
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Забудьте про слик наконец уже, во-первых он умер ещё в 2017 году, во-вторых для него нужен JQ, в третьих - есть Swiper и этим всё сказано.